# Get selected value and assign the array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Play")) {
    int[] selectedIx = playlist.getSelectedIndices();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIx.length; i++) {
        Object sel = playlist.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIx[i]);
        String[] myIntArray = new String[]{"01","02","03"};
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        result.append( myIntArray[1] );
        String mynewstring = result.toString();
        String output = LibraryData.getArtist(mynewstring);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Is it any chance to modify that loop to assign array to selected item from `JList`?

What I mean exactly is:
Get selected item from `JList` ---> If user choose Item 2 which is `model.addElement(list[1])` ---> Then the `myIntArray` should be `02` and send it to String output.

In different words, I want to change the selected item to String `01`, because it is a key which is used to get data about the song from another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line `result.append( myIntArray[1] );`.

Seems it should be `result.append( myIntArray[i] );`

### EDIT

Change 
    `result.append( myIntArray[1] );`
to 
    `result.append( myIntArray[selectedIx[i]] );`

Because you are trying to get the text by selected index.

Comment: Output is always "01" if I changed it to "[i]"

Comment: Yeah, seems we get it at the same time :)

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct because I tried very hard to understand your code :)